# Manipular arquivo .sql

Tags: sql

Tenho um arquivo *.sql. Como faço para transferir/usar num banco de dados?

Ter os registros no banco de dados. (me foi enviado e nao sei ter os dados dentro do meu banco de dados, para depois usar com php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O arquivo *.sql não representa o banco de dados, ele não contém os registros e nem é uma cópia do mesmo.

Esse é um arquivo de **script**, pode conter a criação do banco, queries, criação de tabelas, inserts, e outras operações SQL.

Você pode abrí-lo utilizando desde um editor de texto, mas na maioria deles (pelo menos de forma nativa) não vai conseguir executar esse script.

Como você tinha colocado a tag [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench) na pergunta, você pode abrir o MySQL Workbench, conectar em uma instância do MySQL e abrir o arquivo utilizando <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd> no Windows ou <kbd>⌘O</kbd> no macOS.

Se não tiver nenhuma instância do MySQL instalada, siga [esse link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/instalando-e-configurando-a-nova-versao-do-mysql/25813).

Comment: Obrigada. foi possível criar as tabelas do arquivo.com o uso  do" open sql script " do workbench.  eu  nao consegui compreender alguns conceitos... voce enviou um link ..com a instalação do sql ... voce chamou isso de  instância do MySQL instalada ... qual a diferencia entre o aplicativo  de gerenciamento e a instancia? o workbench  é uma ferramenta para usar o sql ... e essa instancia...   me ajuda se estou toda errada...a entender

Comment: A instância é onde estarão os seus bancos de dados. O workbench é a ferramenta de manipulação, você não precisa necessariamente usá-lo e existem muitos outros.

Answer (score 0):

Olá no se for no phpmyadmin, você deve clicar em importar 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois você clica em procurar e escolher o arquivo sql e logo abaixo você clica em executar. Se não der certo você pode está criando uma base de dados e depois importar os dados... 
Espero te ajudado

Comment: Obrigada eu consegui... mas gostaria de entender um pouco mais... eu tenho no meu computado somente o php7 . eu nao instalei xampetc nenhum pacote, eu uso o php pelo comando do cmd windows. no navegador : localhost:8080  dentro de um pasta especifica que destinei para arquivos web.  tipo isso ( cd www  entro na pasta depois php -s holocahost:8080 .... ) eu acho que nao tenho o phpMyAdim instalado ... como posso saber  ou acessa-lo ? eu escrevi localhost:8080/phpmyadim e deu erro nao localizado...  .

Comment: eu sugiro você instalar o Wamp já que está fazendo isso no seu computador, porque isso facilita o processo. Mas se quiser instalar https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ de forma individual, pode acessar esse site. Mas seria mais complicado. Tem que ver se você tem o phpmyadmin instalado no pc.

Comment: Já que está resolvido, finalize esse forum.